# Are Python's subprocess.call() and Bash streams semantically different?

Tags: python, bash, unix

From bash:

```
$ python script.py < input.txt 2> stderr.txt > stdout.txt
```

In Python:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["python", "script.py"],
                stdin=open('input.txt', 'rb'),
                stdout=open('stdout.txt', 'wb'),
                stderr=open('stderr.txt', 'wb'))
```

Assuming valid `input.txt`, `python` is valid and in the path, etc., these behave identically for the simple case.

Are there any cases where the shell version could behave differently than the Python version?

Comment: Are there any particular effects that you have in mind?

Comment: The goal here is to wrap and test script.py, so mostly I'm concerned about the impact from script.py's perspective.  Is there any difference in what script.py sees in terms of sys.stdin/stdout/stderr?  Any difference in what script.py can do w.r.t. spawning its own subprocesses, different memory limitations, possible performance impact, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any cases where the shell version could behave differently than the Python version?

It depends on what effects you have in mind. The program execution and stream redirections do the exact same thing in your shell line as in your Python script. On the other hand, the shell does effect some other changes to the subprocess, such as putting it into a new process group and making that the foreground process group on the terminal.

**EDIT**: To put into the context of your comment, there *are* differences, but the process group change is the only one I can immediately think of, at least. That's a very tiny difference indeed, and nothing that programs that don't do fairly advanced job-control is going to affected by. There are certainly no changes in memory limitations or any performance impacts, at least. Generally speaking, there are no differences that are going to concern the *vast* majority of programs, at least.

You can, of course, do the same process-group change from within Python as well: See `os.setpgid()` and `os.tcsetpgrp()`.